# Is there an Android ebook reader app that allows to share all notes and highlights as a single Evernote note?

Tags: android

I noticed that FBReader allows me to share any highlight into Evernote, or email, and that's handy, but has to be done repeatedly for every highlight. To save time while reading the book, I'd like to have one step that does exactly that and creates a single note (multiple notes is fine too, I can merge them easily in Evernote). Ultimate goal is just to get all my notes from the android device to my PC. Is there an app that easily lets me do that?